# Stack with CodeIgniter, only index page load

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Controllers/home.php code is:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
}
?>
```

Config/routes.php code is:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

This code is for view only index page. I create folder in views named pitanja, and several pages in that folder. Problem is when i click on site on that pages, i get error 404 page. Where i miss?

Comment: Read this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html and this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views

Comment: Don't need this 'example.com/index.php/blog/' i need this 'example.com/blog/'.... You didn't help me, read carefull. @wolfgang1983

Comment: You want to remove index.php from url ?

Comment: What you mean by view folder.
Is the view file index.php file is inside any folder inside views folder?

Comment: This is how looks my views folder: 1.folder(error) 2.folder(kontakt) 3.folder(pitanja) 4.folder(registrovani_korisnici) index.html and index.php, when i open my browser they display me index.php page, but when i click on link pitanja/index.php they display me 404 error page. How to set that display me that page. @MoizArif

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html
This will helps you ..

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->load->view('pitanja/index');// relative to APPPATH.'views' directory
```

Answer (score -1):

Just store pitanja folder with application|system|user_guid and it will display pages. Solved!